# Selenium raises NoSuchElementException interacting with dropdown within iframe

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am working on following [link](https://election.gov.np/np/page/voter-list-db)

I am not able to even extract first drop down too.
I have been working with selenium version 3.14

I have written following code:

```
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, " \
             "like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36"
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = False
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.get("https://election.gov.np/np/page/voter-list-db")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.XPATH, "//select[@id='state']")))).select_by_value("5")
time.sleep(5)
```

I always get:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with the text as *E-Mail Login* is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://election.gov.np/np/page/voter-list-db")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='bbvrs']")))
    Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='state']")))).select_by_value("5")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: EC_Nepal]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

Comment: wow thanks i never knew this concept what does this i frame actually does?

Comment: @nava Check the embedded links :)

Comment: do i need to write same iframe code for every drop down case as i am getting error everytime on other drop down case can you help in tha?

Comment: If you are within the same iframe, you won't have to. Incase the elements are in different frames then you have to change Selenium's focus accordingly.

Comment: i am able to rarely pass these drop down once in every  10 times by following this idea :(

Comment: Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.

Comment: I have asked new question based as i almost completed my work here is new error i got ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71817549/selenium-error-either-the-element-is-no-longer-attached-to-the-dom-it-is-not```